# Show placeholder text in ReactJS input until click then show "typing"

Tags: reactjs, input, onclick

Once I click the text box some of my div will show a "typing." Before clicking, it should show "this is just a sample."

```html
<input type="text" onClick={this.state}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is really messy, here's the sample code for you. Maybe it'll point you the right direction.

```
import React from "react";

export default class Test extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            someState: ""
        }
        this.onChangeState = this.onChangeState.bind(this);
    }

    onChangeState(e) {
        this.setState({
            someState: //logic here
        })
    }

    render() {
        const {someState} = this.state;
        return (
            <>
                <input type="text" onClick={e => this.onChangeState(e)}>
                State value: {someState}
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

Whenever you click chosen div, you'll call **onChangeState** method where you can manipulate your state. Don't forget that every state update causes rerender.
For more info visit [official React docs](http://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208049/discussion-on-answer-by-sirghi-mihail-react-js-input-type-onclick).

Answer (score 0):

if I understood correctly you want to display the word 'Typing' once you click on the div. 
I think this will help you

```
import React from "react";

export default class Typing extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            yourStateName: ""
        }
        this.onChangeState = this.onChangeState.bind(this);
    }

    onChangeState(e) {
        this.setState({
            yourStateName: "Typing"
        })
    }

    render() {
        const {yourStateName} = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="text" onClick={e => this.onChangeState(e)}>
                value: {yourStateName}
            <div/>
        )
    }
}
```